# How to stabilize IE windows in capybara/ruby environment

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Tests that I run well in Chrome and Firefox appear flaky or blinky in IE9. I understand a java based fix for this is setting a capability

```
caps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
```

I interpreted a rough ruby attempt in the env.rb...

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
case get_browser
when 'ie'
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer
  caps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :internet_explorer, :desired_capabilities => caps)
else
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
end
```

and caught the following nomethod error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `setCapability' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities:0x3e9b218>
```

A ruby fix for this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [Ruby bindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings) page, the capabilities are set like:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.internet_explorer
caps["requireWindowFocus"] = true

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :internet_explorer, :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Comment: @TangibleDream Yes.. He is an expert. If you want to learn more, check out his blog. Lots of knowledge there.

Comment: Thanks for the support @ArupRakshit, however my blog has mainly been about Watir and therefore might not help Capybara users.

Comment: I learned and use in my previous job a lots of tips that I found in your blog, honestly speaking. Basically, you love what you do, and that got reflected in your blog too. Keep helping us.